# Insert default value and extract value from other into new table in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `TimeSheet` table and want to insert default values when pageload in asp.net by inserting ID from Employee table and current date, default value 1, but I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Code:

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TimeSheet_Init]
    @EmpID      int,
    @TimeCheckDate datetime,
    @Day1   int,@Day2   int,@Day3   int,@Day4   int,@Day5   int,
    @Day6   int,@Day7   int,@Day8   int,@Day9   int,@Day10  int,
    @Day11  int,@Day12  int,@Day13  int,@Day14  int,@Day15  int,
    @Day16  int,@Day17  int,@Day18  int,@Day19  int,@Day20  int,
    @Day21  int,@Day22  int,@Day23  int,@Day24  int,@Day25  int,
    @Day26  int,@Day27  int,@Day28  int,@Day29  int,@Day30  int,
    @Day31  int
AS
    INSERT INTO [TimeSheet]([EmpID], [TimeCheckDate], [Day1], [Day2], [Day3], [Day4], [Day5], [Day6], [Day7], [Day8], [Day9], [Day10], [Day11],[Day12], [Day13], [Day14], [Day15], [Day16], [Day17], [Day18], [Day19], [Day20],[Day21], [Day22], [Day23], [Day24], [Day25], [Day26], [Day27], [Day28], [Day29],[Day30], [Day31])
       SELECT 
           Id 
       FROM 
           Employee 
       WHERE 
           WorkingStatusId = '1', getdate(), 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

This query is OK:

```
select Id  
from Employee 
where WorkingStatusId = '1'
```

Comment: Anyone help me please!

Comment: You shouldn't use sp_ prefix for stored procedures. It has a special purpose.

Comment: You should fix your broken database design first!! Don't store values into `Day1` through `Day31` columns - that's brain dead..... use the proper normalization techniques and store those values in a separate table, linked to this main table! And if you want to get a default value inserted - define a default constraint on a column and then **don't use it** in your `INSERT` statement to let SQL Server use the default instead

Comment: @marc_s So, How to implement it?

Comment: @marc_s . So, I design the table TimeSheet(Id, Months, Years) and TimeSheetDay(Id,TimeSheetId, Day1,...Day31) . Is it right?

Comment: @user3035133: ***NO!!!!*** `TimeSheet(Id, Months, Years)` as the main table, and `TimeSheetDay(Id, TimeSheetId, DayNo INT, DayValue INT)` and then you have 1-31 entries in `TimeSheetDay` for each `TimeSheet` entry.

Comment: @marc_s  You mean: DayNo is 1,2,....31 and DayValue is for example in Day 1 Employee ID 1 have 8 working hours? So, the TimeSheetDay must add the EmpID -->TimeSheetDay(Id,EmpID, TimeSheetId, DayNo INT, DayValue INT)

Comment: @marc_s Thank you very much! I redesign may Table follow your recommendation. I'm new to SQL :)

Comment: @marc_s  Could you show me how to add default value to column by both specific values and extracted data from another table? For example: adding default value to TimeSheetDay table by extract EmpID from Employee and Default DayNo is Day of current day and Default DayValue is 8?

Comment: @marc_s Thanks. So, I must put EmpID in TimeSheet instead of TimeSheetDay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86960/discussion-between-user3035133-and-marc-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should separate

- the basic information for a month into the `Timesheet` - this holds the `EmployeeID`, the month and year and whatever other information you need for a full month
- the daily information into a separate table `TimesheetDay` that holds the information for each day; things like the day number (1-31), the value (number of hours worked) etc. - and it's linked to a `Timesheet` entry for a given month

**DO NOT** duplicate any data! You **DO NOT** need the `EmployeeID` on every `TimesheetDay` entry - the linked `Timesheet` row already has that information.

This is basic database design 101 - your tables should look something like this:

[image]

and this would be the script to create those two tables and their constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Timesheet]
(
    [TimeSheetID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimesheetMonth] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimesheetYear] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Timesheet] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TimeSheetID] ASC)
) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetDay]
(
    [TimesheetDayID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimesheetID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DayNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DayValue] [decimal](15, 2) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TimesheetDay] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TimesheetDayID] ASC)
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetDay] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_TimesheetDay_DayValue]  
    DEFAULT ((8.0)) FOR [DayValue]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetDay] WITH CHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TimesheetDay_Timesheet] 
    FOREIGN KEY([TimesheetID])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Timesheet] ([TimeSheetID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimesheetDay] 
CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TimesheetDay_Timesheet]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TimeSheet_Init]
    @EmpID      int,
    @TimeCheckDate datetime,
    @Day1   int,@Day2   int,@Day3   int,@Day4   int,@Day5   int,
    @Day6   int,@Day7   int,@Day8   int,@Day9   int,@Day10  int,
    @Day11  int,@Day12  int,@Day13  int,@Day14  int,@Day15  int,
    @Day16  int,@Day17  int,@Day18  int,@Day19  int,@Day20  int,
    @Day21  int,@Day22  int,@Day23  int,@Day24  int,@Day25  int,
    @Day26  int,@Day27  int,@Day28  int,@Day29  int,@Day30  int,
    @Day31  int

AS
    INSERT INTO [TimeSheet]([EmpID],[TimeCheckDate],[Day1],[Day2],[Day3],[Day4],[Day5],[Day6],[Day7],
                            [Day8],[Day9],[Day10],[Day11],[Day12],[Day13],[Day14],[Day15],
                            [Day16],[Day17],[Day18],[Day19],[Day20],[Day21],[Day22],[Day23],
                            [Day24],[Day25],[Day26],[Day27],[Day28],[Day29],[Day30],[Day31])
    select Id  ,getdate(),1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
    from Employee where WorkingStatusId='1'
```

Comment: I just modified the query above, and it works. Anyway, thanks. :)